# Combining several query results into one table, how is the results order determined?

Tags: sql

I am retuning table results for different queries but each table will be in the same format and will all be in one final table. If I want the results for query 1 to be listed first and query2 second etc, what is the easiest way to do it?

Does UNION append the table or are is the combination random?

Answer (score 4):

The SQL standard does not guarantee an order unless explicitly called for in an order by clause.  In practice, this usually comes back chronologically, but I would not rely on it if the order is important.

Across a union you can control the order like this...

```
select
   this,
   that
from
   (
   select
      this,
      that
   from
       table1
   union
   select
     this,
     that
   from
     table2
   )
order by
   that,
   this;
```

Comment: My sql is Oracle syntax.  Not sure if this is implemented the same for other RDBMS.

Comment: another way to control order is to put a
"1 as rank" field in the first part and then a "2 as rank" in the second part, and then "order by rank"

Answer (score 1):

UNION appends the second query to the first query, so you have all the first rows first.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
SELECT Col1, Col2,...
FROM (
    SELECT Col1, Col2,..., 1 AS intUnionOrder
    FROM ...
) AS T1
UNION ALL (
    SELECT Col1, Col2,..., 2 AS intUnionOrder
    FROM ...
) AS T2
ORDER BY intUnionOrder, ...
```